# How to get mathfrak required font

Tags: amsfonts

Currently I am using `amsfont` package use the command of `\mathfrak{J}`.

So i am getting `EUFM10` font viewed.

But I need `cmsy10` font looks like below image:

[image]

How to get the required cmsy10 mathfrak font.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

$\mathfrak{J}$

\end{document}
```

Please advice how to get the required `cmsy10` font.

Comment: cmsy10 does not have fraktur, it has symbols and calligraphic letters (\mathcal) see http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m308/code/psfonts/cmsy10.gif for example.

Comment: @carlisle Ok I understand. This is not mathfrak. How to define the particular symbol. The symbol viewed in cmsy font as you mentioned link.

Comment: @Carlisle Sorry This is math symbol $\Im$. I got it.

Comment: oh I forgot those two: they are more or less fraktur, but not a complete alphabet just R and I for just real and imaginary

Comment: You find the symbol in table 195 of the Comprehensive LaTeX List of Symbols (2015 edition), table 139 in the 2009 edition.

Comment: @egreg Your links are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cm fonts do not have a complete fraktur alphabet but there are symbols for Real and Imaginary part of a complex number so `\Im` in this case.